# EchoNest API Search for song by ID

Tags: api, echonest

I am using Echo nest to make a new web app.  Firstly, I'm searching for a song by song title and artist.  This returns what I'm looking for.  One of the items I want back is the song id, which I get.

Now, I want to be able to search for that exact song later with the song ID, but the search provided on their API site does not search for what I'm looking for.

If you do a search for "Radioactive" by Imagine Dragons, you'll get this as the search: http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=KEY&results=20&sort=song_hotttnesss-desc&title=radioactive&artist=imagine%20dragons

Great, I'm able to get some call backs.  The song I'm looking for has the ID of `SOJGTBJ143947F080F`.

I'm going to save this into a database to callback later.  But when I try to search for the song using the echo nest song search, I get nothing back:
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/track/profile?api_key=KEY&id=SOJGTBJ143947F080F

Now, where is my problem here?  Am I using the wrong search API?  am I not looking at the right ID?  Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer for any one looking for the same thing.  You'll need to look into the "Profile" part of the API.

My lookup URL is now:
http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/profile?api_key=KEY&format=json&id=SOJGTBJ143947F080F

This finds the one and only song I was looking for.

Comment: Echonest api seems is down.